# How do you deal with a high Feature/Sample ratio?

Tags: regularization, dimensionality-reduction, small-sample

I am working on a machine learning task with a small dataset of 130 samples, each with 66 features. When I try to fit a model to this data, I encounter issues with either overfitting or underfitting.

I have tried [ElasticNet](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html), and a PyTorch-based perceptron, but they encounter similar issues. I cannot collect more data due to cost and time constraints.

How can I handle my high-dimensional data with limited samples?

###### Extra

I am particularly interested in feature selection/reduction techniques, regularization methods, and any other tips to prevent overfitting in such scenarios. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the distribution of Y look like?  I doubt that 130 samples is sufficient for analyzing **one pre-specified predictor**.  For approaches such as the ones you considered to work you might need a bare minimum of $15 \times 66$ observations is Y is continuous with a nice distribution.  Your only hope is to only ask questions of the data that the data are capable of answering, e.g., use data reduction/unsupervised learning masked to Y to develop 2-5 summary predictors (using variable cluster or sparse PCA e.g.) then fit a single model with this 2-5 summary variables.

Comment: For more see [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/impred.html) and [this](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata.html).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you! That sounds like great advice, I have been thinking about this problem since and thought that might be the case. Can you go a bit more indepth on the $15 \times 66$ observations part. Do you mean I need 66 observations with 15 categories, or 990 observations? If so, why $15 \times 66$?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Is the link you've provided your own work on the best way to deal with datasets of the size I've mentioned? If so, how deep does the work go into why modelling with such a small sample size fails?

Comment: 990 observations plus 96 to estimate the intercept.  The 15:1 rule is a very rough rule of thumb.  Better: https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.7992 .  Chapter 4 of [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/multivar.html) goes into the failure and covers some data reduction methods that lower the effective number of features you need to play against Y.  A link I provided earlier has a case study in one of the most promising methods: sparse PCA.  The failure of unstructured analysis with small N relates to high standard errors of effect estimates and zero chance of selecting the "right" features.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I started reading the reference you posted. What led you to your 15 EPP rule of thumb? Is it field dependent?

Comment: Unlike the better reference I provided by R Riley, the 15:1 rule of thumb was developed by fitting time-to-event models where the effective sample size is the number of events.  I started with an adequate training sample size and a validation sample and gradually reduced the training sample size until the model's apparent predictive discrimination (generalization of $c$-index, i.e., AUROC) was not as good (in some meaningful way) in the training sample as it was in the test sample.  Chapter 4 of RMS covers several response variable types.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I have an onwards question about some of the terminology used in your first paper on continuous predictions. It would be great if you could look at it  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621727/what-does-small-optimism-in-predictor-effect-mean