# What does small optimism in predictor effect mean?

Tags: regression, sample-size, predictor, small-sample, multivariate-regression

I'm reading the following paper by Burke et al.

[Minimum sample size for developing a multivariable prediction model: Part I – Continuous outcomes](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.7993)

The paper discusses the minimum number of samples required to avoid overfitting when creating regression models. They establish four criteria to avoid this.

Their first criteria is the following:

> i) Small optimism in predictor effect estimates as defined by a global
> shrinkage factor of ≥0.9.

What does this mean in a pratcical sense?

Answer (score 2):

Loosely speaking that means that less than 10% of what you learned is noise.  The real definition is that there is a limited amount by which small predictions are too small and large predictions are too large, i.e., the slope of the calibration curve is between 0.9 and 1.0.  The calibration curve is a plot of y=actual x=predicted.  The shrinkage factor is the slope of the calibration curve when the calibration curve is estimated unbiasedly, either by correcting for overfitting or by using a holdout sample.

Comment: So for something like $y=mx+c$, you'd have an $m$ equal to a value between 0.9 and 1.0? If this is the case, why can't it be over 1.0, and why is it called the shrinkage factor?

Comment: It can be over 1.0 if you have _underfitting_.  One reason it's called the shinkage factor is that you can use it to shrink your predictions towards the mean prediction to make them better calibrated.  That's "after the fact shrinkage".  Active shrinkage is the use of penalization which in the machine learning world is called for some reason regularization.